# Вопрос по слову Карукота

Tags: правописание

Всем доброго времени суток!
Я несколько лет составляю кроссворды, сейчас составляю базу слов. Хочу создать базу слов, не содержащую ошибок. В интернете часто встречается слово "карукота", но его можно увидеть на тех сайтах, которые созданы якобы в помощь кроссвордистам. На этих сайтах карукота - английская мера площади. Но этого слова я не встречал ни в словарях, ни в энциклопедиях, ни в википедии. Подскажите, пожалуйста, может быть там одна или несколько опечаток? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Наверняка, этим когда-то придётся воспользоваться для решения, но на предмет составления лучше снабдите это пометкой, что подтверждения применяемости термина и его толкования не найдено. Пока впечатление такое, что эта "кроссвордная статья" переходит от одних составителей к другим. В детстве один знакомый продемонстрировал мне способ решения кроссвордов, называя на ходу изобретаемые слова, которые всё равно не с чем сверить. Здесь возможно всё, вплоть до попадания вымысла из какой-нибудь фэнтеси-книжки. В сети есть сборники английских современных и устаревших единиц измерения, ничего похожего там не видно.